# Replace delimiter( | ) inside ""(Double Quotes)

Tags: c#, ssis

I have to remove `|` inside a double quote (`"`) and replace with `-`

Example:

**Actual :**

```
("Some Txt | www.google.com")
```

**Expected :**

```
("Some Txt - www.google.com")
```

Comment: And...What's your problem?

Comment: I assume you've already tried `string.Replace()`, in which case there is some further information about your problem you need to tell us. For example, do you have a string containing nested quote-delimited strings, and it is only within those substrings that you want to replace the `|`?

Comment: I would chech if it matched the criteria `"something |` using [ssis - findstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [ssis - substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to replace the | with -, if the character is inside double quotes, you can use this method:

```
private static string ReplaceWithinQuotes(string input, char from, char to)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(input);
        bool withinQuotes = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if(input[i] == '\"')
            {
                withinQuotes = !withinQuotes;
            }
            if(withinQuotes && input[i] == from)
            {
                sb[i] = to;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

The method first copies the string into a string builder. Then it is looped over the string and checked whether we are inside quotes. The state is stored inside a bool. If we are inside quotes, in the string builder the character is replaced.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hdlu4U

Comment: Not sure about the viability. OP has the SSIS tag in his question

Comment: To those who curious  *why* `StringBuilder` is required: to [subtly create](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,101) `char[]` and manipulate that. Though explicitly creating array may be a prefferable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string replace method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Some Txt | www.google.com";
string result = str.Replace('|', '-');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var newString = ("Some Txt | www.google.com").Replace("|", "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to use the build in Replace method ([Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_Char_System_Char_)).

```cs
string result = "Some Txt | www.google.com".Replace('|', '-');
```

Have great times coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a derived column with the function [REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/replace-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
REPLACE(YourColumn, "|", "-")
REPLACE("Some Txt | www.google.com", "|", "-")
```